# How to get All Field (Column Name) in any Table(Like Account ,Lead) from SalesForce?

Tags: c#, salesforce

I don't have any idea about Salesforce. I need to get the **All column Name** from a **Table** in **SalesForce**. For example in `Account` table I need FieldNames like `MasterRecordId`, `Id` ,`AccountNumber`, `OwnerId`, etc,. they must be **json object**.
Please help me.

Comment: Possibly, you can find useful this similar discussion - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49711/howto-wildcard-select-to-query-all-fields-of-objects-in-apex

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would just be to export the table into Excel with DataLoader.

It isn't done with code, but if you just need the column names then it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SObject Describe api call to get the list of fields on the object, and then build your soql query.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_describe.htm